# Only first char of user input used in array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am writing some code for a nanokernel, which means I can't use the standard library, although I have implemented functions for printing strings and getting chars from the keyboard.

Right now I have the program set up to take chars from the keyboard and put them into an array. The string is then printed out. I expect the string printed out to look exactly like what was inputted by the user.

The issue is that it seems that the only char being put into the string is the first char inputted on the keyboard.

here is the relevant code for putting the chars into an array:

```
void stringin(char str[]) { // takes a string, puts it in str
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\033';) {
                str[i] = getch();
                if (str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\033') {
                        i++;
                }
                calctime(1000000); // waits for a bit so that we don't flood the array
        }
        if (str[i] == '\n') newline(1);
        str[i++] = '\0';
}
```

I have used both a printing function and a strcmp() implementation to test the contents of the string, so nothing seems to be going wrong with printing the string.

Comment: For starters,`prt[1] = '\0';` addresses outside the bounds of the array `prt` which is declared to have length 1.  The only valid index is 0.

Comment: I'm terminating it with a null char.

Comment: Yes.  You are placing 2 chars in the array.  But your array is length 1.

Comment: Arrays start at 0 in C.

Comment: exactly my point.  ;)

Comment: Well, that part of the code works fine. str is just messed up after the function is used.

Comment: at first check in your loop when `i=0`, what is the value of `str[0]`? is it initialized?  How is the loop supposed to exit if `i` is one more than the index of the last character read?

Comment: Nothing has been put into str yet. the variable passed as an argument to stringin() was declared with char string[10]. The loop exits when the either the enter or escape key is pressed.

Comment: OK.  Then there's your error.  Add some debugging prints and you will see.

Comment: Always try to create a [mcve] to show us. How do you call this function? What do you pass as argument to the function? What is its contents? And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If `getch()` can return any character and a distinct value EOF, it probably returns an `int`, and saving that directly into `str[i]` loses some information.  The loop control is also dubious to my way of thinking; if `str[0]` ever holds a newline, you'll never get anywhere with the loop — and it could hold newline when the function is called (at least, it isn't obvious that it can't).  Similarly with `\033` ESC.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, `str` is passed to `stringin` with the buffer uninitialized.

Since the following loop terminates based on the value of `str[i]` before `str[i]` is actually initialized, the results are undefined.

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\033';) {
    str[i] = getch();
    ....
```